# Making calculations in another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm writing a C# windows form application in VS2010.
I have a function that makes a lot of calculations. And when I press button with this function my programm stops responding any clicks till the calculation is over.

How can I make Window Form and these calculations run parallel?

Comment: Have you tried to google about threads in .net?

Comment: I used this tutorial a couple of days ago: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

- You can use a [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), easy to use - will use the  built in threadpool, less
  overhead compare to if you use a new [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).
- You can also use an deligate, like [action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx), and call [begininvoke.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) With a callback.

**Example (backgroundworker):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var back = new BackgroundWorker();
            back.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(back_DoWork);
            back.RunWorkerCompleted += new  RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(back_RunWorkerCompleted);
            back.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        //Do work here (not safe to call control elemnts here - if so, use this.invoke(deligate);
        private decimal myResult = 0;
        void back_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            myResult = 5 + 5;
        }

        //Update form here - threadsafe
        void back_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "result: " + myResult.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example begininvoke:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action DoWork = new Action(CalcHere);
        DoWork.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(CallBack), null);
    }

    //Work here
    private decimal myResult = 0;
    private void CalcHere()
    {
        myResult = 5 + 5;
    }

    //callback here
    private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => { label1.Text = "Result: " + myResult.ToString(); }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Look at the Fibonacci calculator sample in the documentation.

Comment: @Maess that was only true for previous versions of the CLR afaik.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculations = new Thread(() => DoCalculations());

private void DoCalculations() {
    // Do long work
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this work for you?

```
public class Calculator
{
    public void doHeavyCalculations()
    {
       //Do what you want to here.
    }

};
```

On your onButtonClick, you can do:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator();
Thread mThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart(calc.doHeavyCalculations) );

mThread.Start(); //This will start the work

/*
Make some code to show a messagebox to tell users to wait while the calculations are being done. Dont forget to tell the form to update, so it'll show the progress.
*/
```

Comment: Its overhead to use new thread in this case. Backgroundworker is to prefer.